# Implement functions for the buttons in the installshiel dialog

Tags: dialog, installshield, installscript

I am currently working on installshield to create an installer for my project.
I created a new dialog but I don't know how to make my buttons work. Can someone guide me a bit on this.
Project Type - MSI Basic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVlvB.png)

I tried adding the installScript file but I can't link it to my dialog.